# Confidentiality of Google's Vertex AI API

Tags: vertex, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm using a FireStore extension called [Chatbot with PaLM API](https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/firestore-palm-chatbot) which uses Google Cloud's Vertex AI's API behind the scenes. My prompts may contain sensitive and confidential data, so I'm trying to ascertain the level of confidentiality Google guarantees for these. Azure, for example, [very clearly states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/openai/data-privacy) that prompts to the it's Azure OpenAI Service are not used for training, and that it is possible to opt out of content monitoring.